# using JMock to write unit test for a simple spring JDBC DAO

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, jmock

I'm writing an unit test for spring jdbc dao. The method to test is:

```
public long getALong() {
return simpleJdbcTemplate.queryForObject("sql query here", new RowMapper<Long>() {
  public Long mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
    return resultSet.getLong("a_long");
  }
});
```

}

Here is what I have in the test:

```
public void testGetALong() throws Exception {
    final Long result = 1000L;
    context.checking(new Expectations() {{
      oneOf(simpleJdbcTemplate).queryForObject("sql_query", new RowMapper<Long>() {
        public Long mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
          return resultSet.getLong("a_long");
        }
      });
      will(returnValue(result));
    }});
    Long seq = dao.getALong();
    context.assertIsSatisfied();
    assertEquals(seq, result);
  }
```

Naturally, the test doesn't work (otherwise, I wouldn't be asking this question here). The problem is the rowmapper in the test is different from the rowmapper in the DAO. So the expectation is not met.

I tried to put `with` around the sql query and `with(any(RowMapper.class))` for the rowmapper. It wouldn't work either, complains about "not all parameters were given explicit matchers: either all parameters must be specified by matchers or all must be specified by values, you cannot mix matchers and values"

Comment: Take a look at the RowMapper Test usage from Github by Poutsma itself: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/3.1.x/org.springframework.jdbc/src/test/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapperTests.java

Answer (score 2):

Provide a matcher for query string as well, e.g.

```
  oneOf(simpleJdbcTemplate).queryForObject(
      with( equal("sql_query") ),
      with( any(RowMapper.class) )
  );
```

Comment: nope, it doesn't work neither. I'm getting "not all parameters were given explicit matchers: either all parameters must be specified by matchers or all must be specified by values, you cannot mix matchers and values" error.

Comment: @Quincy, the `)` was missing after `sql_query`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be missing a couple of points here. Your first attempt reproduced the behaviour of the target code in the mock. What are you really trying to test?

For this kind of test, I prefer to write a focussed test that hits a real database. I tried mocking out the JDBC many years ago and regretted it. What usually fails in this kind of code is the relationship with the database, rather than the java code itself.

This is really a query (it doesn't change the state of the world outside the object), so I tend to use an `allowing()` clause rather than `oneOf()`. It's the same underlying mechanism but expresses the intent better.

Finally, rather than calling `context.assertIsSatisfied()` directly, consider using

```
@RunWith(JMock.class)
```

at the top of the test.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding `with(any(Object.class))` at the end.

```
oneOf(jdbcTemplate).queryForObject(with(equal("sql_query")), with(any(RowMapper.class)), with(any(Object.class)));
```

I think jmock was having trouble finding the right method to call, since queryForObject method get overloaded so much.

Comment: Would be nice of you to tell us that the method you are testing takes 3 arguments, instead of 2.